# MATLAB - How to calculate uniformity of an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to get uniformity value of an image intensity. In the description sheet it described as the following:

General Description

> If Z is a random variable indicating image intensity, its *n*th moment around the mean is
> [image]
>
> where *m* is the mean of *Z*, *p(.)* its histogram and *L* is the number of intensity levels.

For Uniformity

> Uniformity, defined as
>
> [image]
>
> uniformity's maximum value is reached when all intensity levels are equal.

What I do not understand and I want to know is p and L actually. I do not know how to calculate them. Additionally, what is *(.)* for, in *p(.)*?

**EDIT**

```
% V component of HSV image, contains 0~1 values in double type
% size(Iv) = 960 720
Z = Iv(:);

IL = unique(Z);        % Get all intensity levels
noinle = numel(IL);    % Number of intensity levels
p = hist(Ivc, noinle); % Histogram

U = 0;

for i = 1:noinle
    U = U + sum( p(i,:).^2 );
end
```

This operation results very big numbers which are not compatible in the sample dataset given. They all are double numbers between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your image is stored in an array called `Img`, you can obtain `L` and `p` with the following code:

```
IL = unique(Img(:));      % Get all intensity levels
L = numel(IL);            % Number of intensity levels
p = histogram(Img, IL);   % Histogram
```

Best,

Comment: `L = numel(L);` or `L = numel(IL);`?

Comment: `p = histogram(Img, IL);` causes undefined function error. Could it be `p = hist(Img, IL);`?

Comment: Yes, depending on your Matlab version. `histrogram` has been introduced in the recent releases, `hist` still works but will probably be removed in the future.

Comment: Thank you, I have applied your answer. But I get strange values. If you look at U equation in my question, I get huge values. But in the dataset all the uniformity values are ranged between 0 to 1. Please see my editted question.

Comment: Are the intensity values in your image ranged between 0 and 1 ? Or 0 and 255 ? Without proper normalization you will get large values. though I'm not a specialist, I suspect that the algorithm works with values between 0 and 1.

Comment: Z vector contains 0~1 values in double type

Answer (score 1):

Unless its defined in the paper otherwise generally these are the definitions:

`p` is the histogram of the image. What this is a break down of the colors in the image put into buckets. In matlab the function for this is `h = histogram(x,nbins)`.

`L` is the number of buckets. Generally this is something you decide based on your application.